# HOW to Call NIFI REST API to START/STOP generate flow file

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to call Start and Stop Generate flow file using NIFI REST API.

For example from python or shell script I can call NIFI Generate flow file using NIFI REST API

Comment: have a look at this - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/start-stop-processor-via-nifi-api/td-p/117144

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python to interact with the NiFi API, consider using [NiPyAPI](https://pypi.org/project/nipyapi/)

Specifically, you can start and stop processors using:

```
nipyapi.canvas.schedule_processor
```

See the docs here:
https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nipyapi-docs/nipyapi.html#nipyapi.canvas.schedule_processor

```
nipyapi.canvas.schedule_processor(processor, scheduled, refresh=True)

Set a Processor to Start or Stop.

Note that this doesn’t guarantee that it will change state, merely that it will be instructed to try. Some effort is made to wait and see if the processor starts
Parameters: 

    processor (ProcessorEntity) – The Processor to target
    scheduled (bool) – True to start, False to stop
    refresh (bool) – Whether to refresh the object before action

Returns:    

True for success, False for failure
Return type:    

(bool)
```